# How to display PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to display PDF's using PHP which are stored in a folder named uploads which is located in the same folder with my php file .

this is the code I tried:
(aa is the name of the pdf file)

```
  $file1 = '\uploads\aa.php';
      header('Content-type: application/pdf');
      header('Content-Disposition : inline; filename="' . $file1 . '"');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

   @readfile($file1);
```

but I get a server error :

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

is there any soluion for this?

Comment: Check the error logs, also `\upload\` would mean the file would be in the root of the server, not in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking a look at your path, and I see that you are using backslashes `\` instead of a forward slash `/` and presuming you are not using Windows, it should be instead a `/`

example:

```php
$file1 = 'uploads/aa.php';
      header('Content-type: application/pdf');
      header('Content-Disposition : inline; filename="' . $file1 . '"');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

   @readfile($file1);
```

more information on it here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp